# Example of arc consistency does not imply satisfiability

Tags: artificial-intelligence, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I've read that arc consistency does not imply satisfiability.
The provided example was

```
X in D ∧ Y in D ∧ X ≠ Y ∧ X = Y
```

for domains D with more than one value.

My understanding is that for each of the possible values of X (from D) there are values of Y (from the same D) such that the above constraint is satisfied.

Could someone please give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-explanation-of-arc-consistency-in-constraint-satisfaction-problems) explanation and I think I understood my mistake.

Arc consistency it's about *atomic constraints*

> A constraint is consistent if a subproblem, containing only that
>   constraint and its variables and their domains:
>
> - has a solution
> - there is a solution when an arbitrary variable gets an arbitrary    value from its domain

So in my case the atomic constraints `X ≠ Y` and `X = Y` are arc consistent, where `X in D ∧ Y in D` and `D` has more than one value.